# Custom loop request based on custom field

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, sort

I have many post, all categorized. So 100 post, 40 in cat=4. All those 40 post have a custom field name point with a rating in there (how many point win). Si the question How to loop through all the post, and get ONLY the post with cat=4, and sort those post base on the point score in the custom field, and display, post title, and point. So the output will look like :

- john : 134pt
- paul : 124pt
- kim : 100pt
- joe : 90 pt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [WP_Query in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for info on how to [query on custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'cat' => 4,
    'meta_key' => 'point_score',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
);

$points_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while( $points_query->have_posts() ):
    $points_query->the_post();
    the_title();
    echo ' : ';
    echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'point_score', true );
endwhile;
```

Comment: get_post_meta echo the output.. i like to have it in a var... exept for that... the rest look like working

Comment: that page answer a lot of questions : http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, here is the final working code

```
function mam_listing($args) {

    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'cat' => 6,
    'meta_key' => 'Points',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
    );

$outputt = '<table width="100%" cellpadding="2" border="0">';
$no=0;

$points_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while(  $points_query->have_posts() ):
        $points_query->the_post();

        $no = $no+1;

        $outputt .= '<tr>';

        $outputt .= '<td>';
        $outputt .= 'Position '.$no;
        $outputt .= '</td>';

        $outputt .= '<td>';
        $outputt .= '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . get_the_title($post->ID) .'</a>';
        $outputt .= '</td>';

        $outputt .= '<td>';
        $temp = get_post_custom_values("Points");
        $outputt .= $temp[0];
        $outputt .= " Points";
        $outputt .= '</td></tr>';
endwhile;

$outputt .= '</table>';

    return  $outputt;
}

add_shortcode( 'mam-listing', 'mam_listing' );
```